# Ubuntu 22.10 .Net Core 6 `dotnet nuget locals all -c` DOES NOT WORK

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, dotnet-cli, ubuntu-22.04

I keep getting the stale / old symbol references in VSCode, both "intelli"sense and build error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have to close VSCode, run `dotnet nuget locals all -c` and relaunch VSCode....